# Optimizing MySQL View with aggregate function

Tags: mysql, optimization, view, aggregate

I have this view:

```
CREATE VIEW invoicereport
SELECT i.ID, SUM(o.Amount * o.Price) AS Total
FROM invoice i
JOIN `order` o ON i.ID = o.InvoiceID
GROUP BY i.ID
```

Running this query directly takes 0.03 seconds.
But running the view takes 2 seconds. even when I do `SELECT * FROM invoicereport WHERE ID=9000` it still takes 2 seconds.

So I rewrite the view to:

```
CREATE VIEW invoicereport
SELECT i.ID, (SELECT SUM(Amount * Price) FROM `order` WHERE InvoiceID=i.ID) AS Total
FROM invoice i
```

Thought the subquery will only be executed for ID 9000.
Then when I do `SELECT * FROM invoicereport WHERE ID=9000` it is even more slow, takes 3 seconds to completed.

Is there any other way to optimize this query?

Comment: [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to join these tables, just grouping `order` would be suffice. (just my opinion). Like this:

```
CREATE VIEW INVOICEREPORT
SELECT O.INVOICEID as ID, SUM(O.AMOUNT * O.PRICE) AS TOTAL
FROM `ORDER` O
GROUP BY O.INVOICEID
```

Then you can join this view with others. And use indexes on `order`.

Comment: Table invoice contains other information such as Customer Name, Tel, etc.

Comment: Try like this:

    `select i.id, i.customer_name, i.tel, ir.total 
    from invoice i 
    join invoicereport ir on ir.id = i.id`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comment by Kuya John.  On such a simple summation, don't even bother trying to do it as a view.  The simplicity of it is unnecessary to do a join.  There was another answer I provided a few years back of a similar where someone was using existing views and his query was some obscene amount of time.  When I asked to go back to the raw tables for the query and write it direct, the query was STILL very simple to read and extremely fast.  Don't use a view, just have as direct select statement.

Views like sub-selects are TYPICALLY query-time killers and I try to always avoid them both.

Since you are looking for other invoice data too, should be no issue to get... but bigger confirmation... does your orders table have an index on the Invoice ID?

```
SELECT 
      I.ID, 
      I.Customer_Name,
      I.Tel,
      SUM(o.Amount * o.Price) AS Total
   FROM 
      invoice I
         JOIN `order` o ON I.ID = O.InvoiceID
   WHERE
      I.ID = 9000
   GROUP BY 
      I.ID
```

Comment: InvoiceID is an index. Also the actual query is much more complex than this, it contains COUNT(o.ID) AS OrderCount, SUM(IF(mg.Type='Food',1,0)) AS FoodCount, SUM(IF(mg.Type='Drink',1,0)) AS DrinkCount, etc. And `order` joined with `menu` which joined with `menugroup`